# Random array string assigned to a text component - Unity 4.6, uGUI

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Need some help with this one. I'm creating an array with a list of descriptions (strings) that I need to choose randomly and then assign to a text component in a gameobject.

I feel like I'm close but I'm getting an error:

> Type `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for `Next' and no extension method `Next' of type `UnityEngine.Random' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What should I be using instead of 'Next'?

```
public Text myText;
Random rand = new Random();

public string[] animalDescriptions = 
{
    "Description 1",
    "Description 2",
    "Description 3",
    "Description 4",
    "Description 5",
};

void Start()
{
    string myString = animalDescriptions[rand.Next(animalDescriptions.Length)];
    myText.text = myString;

    Debug.Log (myString);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have conflicting namespaces. Use the fully qualified name instead (System.Random)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like when you don't use it's full name, your `Random` will be referring to `UnityEngine.Random` not [`System.Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class (because you have already used this in your namespace etc..).

Use it's full name as;

```
System.Random rand = new System.Random();
```

or change your `UnityEngine.Random` name to something else (which I suggest).

Comment: that's strange, these are the only namespaces I'm using: using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;, Am I missing a namespace to use Random?